# Is there any way this code can be condensed?

Tags: jquery, html, input

This code is for 4 checkboxes.

When the first 3 boxes are checked the 4th needs to be checked,
when the 4th is unchecked the first 3 should uncheck and 
if all 4 boxes are checked and 1 of the first 3 are unchecked the 4th should uncheck.

The issue is this code needs to repeated 7 times with different id's used.
ie #a1 will be #b1 or #a4 will be #d4.

```
$('#a1, #a2, #a3, #a4').change(function() {
if ($(this).is('#a1, #a2, #a3')) {
  if ($('#a4').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('#a4').prop('checked', false);
  }

  if ($('#a1:checked').length === $('#a1').length && $('#a2:checked').length === $('#a2').length && $('#a3:checked').length === $('#a3').length) {
    $('#a4').prop('checked', true);
  }
}
if ($(this).is('#a4')) {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#a1, #a2, #a3').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
  }
  else {
    $('#a1, #a2, #a3').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
      }
    }
});
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cwLhdcwL/

To split blocks of checkboxes use: `data-area` attribute.

`#a4, #b4, ...` elements should be marked by `data-role="cb-master"` attribute, while `#a[1..3], #b[1..3], ...` elements should be marked by `data-role="cb-child"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for this, I did not test this though so

Javascript: default.js

```
function checkCheckbox(checkbox) {
    if (cb1.checked === true && cb2.checked === true && cb3.checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('cb4').checked = true;
    }

    // To work the other way: if checkbox 4 is checked then check all others
    else if (cb4.checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('cb1').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('cb2').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('cb3').checked = true;
    }
}

// For older browsers
function checkCheckbox(checkbox) {
    if (document.getElementById('cb1').value === true && document.getElementById('cb2').value === true && document.getElementById('cb3').value === true) {
        document.getElementById('cb4').checked = true;
    }

    // To work the other way: if checkbox 4 is checked then check all others
    else if (document.getElementById('cb4').value === true) {
        document.getElementById('cb1').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('cb2').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('cb3').checked = true;
    }
}
```

HTML: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Checkbox Example
    </title>
    <script src="default.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" onclick="checkCheckbox" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" onclick="checkCheckbox" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" onclick="checkCheckbox" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="cb4" onclick="checkCheckbox" />
  </body>
</html>
```